# Conectar a instancia SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Boa noite amigos.

Tenho instalado em uma maquina SERVIDOR um sistema que utiliza o SQL SERVER, a maquina cliente fica em outra cidade, pra conectar as duas na mesma rede fizemos uma VPN utilizando o próprio WIN 7.

A maquina Cliente não consegue de jeito nenhum acessar a instancia do SQL Server para executar o sistema, o estranho é que quando faço teste de conexao utilizando alguma ferramente o conexão com  instancia sql apresenta SUCESSO.

Testando a conexao via ODBCAD32 ocorro erro 10060.

O firewall das duas maquinas esta desativado.
Antivirus desativado.
SSMS liberado para conexao remota
SQL Server Manager ja configurado e liberado com protocolo TCP e porta 1433

Não sei mais o que fazer, parece que ele nao aceita acessar a instancia do sql quando utilizo o .exe que abre o sistema.

Poderiam me ajudar.

Desde ja agradeço. Obrigado.

Comment: Isso parece ser problema de permissões.

Comment: Boa tarde. Permissão do cliente na VPN ? Estou pesquisando nao encontrei nada ainda sobre como dar permissao especifica para o cliente na porta da instancia.

Comment: Consegui resolver refazendo a VPN, e desmarcando a opção de pegar o gateway padrao.